# how to calculate power budget calculation for new project? Need basic steps to start

Tags: pcb-design

Could you please let me know how to calculate power budgeting of new project. What are the things i need to consider while power budgeting. what are the main points keep in mind while doing safe and effective power budgeting?

Comment: What do you mean for new project? you built/designed soemthing and now want to calculate its power? Or you have nothing yet and want to pull some maximum power figures out of thin air?

Comment: i am going to start new project so i am collecting what are the main technical information are required before going to start. Now i am in initial phase to study and collect what all are the required details in my side with all your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are in the early (preliminary, feasibility) phase of a project you can make a very rought estimate based on similar projects done in the past, or by (tentatively) inditifying the most power-hungry sub-part(s) and calculating their consumption. Multiply this for instance by two for a margin. If the value you come up with does not raise any eybrows power will likely not be a problem in your project.

In later phases you divide the total power budget into what seems reasonable for the subsystems and give that as a budget for each subsystem designer. He designs according to that spec and everybody is happy.

Things get more interesting when power (or any other resource) is scarce. That requires (system) engineering, which is not something that can be explained here, even a book would not be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for accepting, but note that it is considered good practice to wait at least 24 hourse before accepting. The perfect answer might still be in the head of someone who is asleep now.

Comment: thanks, based on your valid information i just calculate to add my processor, interfaces IC's and supporting IC's power consumption in full load condition and multiply into 2 is my maximum power of my project in initial stage. Am i right?

Comment: oh you are correct and thanks for the kind information.

Comment: Better explain your full project. 'supporting ICs' is too vaugue: a 74HC595 will consume almost nothing, but an Ethernet or WiFi support chip will likely draw more power than the rest of your system combined. If you just want to flash a LED, that LED will likely conusme more than your processor. If your system draws very little power, your batteries (you are going for batteries I assume, otherwise power calculations are much less interesting) self-discharge might be more important than what your system consumes.

Comment: (I seem to be in Russell-mode) If you have a modern micro-controller, its clock frequency and/or enabled peripherals might make a big difference. In most cases you would design the system to be active only in short bursts, to reduce overall power consumption.